# How can I draw two loops above a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw two loops above a node? Here is my code:

```
\path (r) edge[loop above] node[left=1pt] {3} (r);
\path (r) edge[out=140, in=50, looseness=0.8, loop] node[above=3pt] {4} (r);
```

How can I make the 2nd loop bigger, so that I get more space in between the loops?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the `distance` key, which sets both `min distance` and `max distance` (ignoring any computation).  If you want less control, you can just specify one of those two.  For more information, check out section 44.3, "Curves", of the PGF manual.

---

An example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw,fill,circle,minimum size=.15cm] (r) at (0,0) {} ;
  \path (r) edge[loop above] node[left=1pt] {3} (r);
  \path (r) edge[ out=140, in=50
                , looseness=0.8, loop
                , distance=2cm, ->]
            node[above=3pt] {4} (r);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This produces the picture

[image: Two loops of different heights.]