# changing loop size and shape in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to make the small loop around the circle (loop above) a bit rounder and nicer.

below is a short example of my code:

```
 \documentclass{scrbook}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,auto]
   \tikzstyle{place}=[circle,thick,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20,minimum
                      size=6mm]
   \node[place] (foo) [label=above left:Foo] {$1$};
   \path[->] (foo) edge  [loop above] node {1} ();
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image: example from the previous code]

Comment: Somewhat related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7774/how-can-i-draw-two-loops-above-a-node/7781#7781

Answer (score 39):

There are four parameters that you can play with to adjust the `loop` size and shape.  You can set the `in` and `out` angles, and also the minimum length for a loop and its `looseness`. See Section 50.4 of the TikZ documentation for more detail:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{every loop/.style={min distance=10mm,in=0,out=60,looseness=10}}
\tikzset{place/.style={circle,thick,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20,minimum
                      size=6mm}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,auto]   
   \node[place] (foo) [label=above left:Foo] {$1$};
   \path[->] (foo) edge  [loop above] node {1} ();
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

I've used `\tikzset` to set them globally in this example; you can also add the `.style` specification to an individual `tikzpicture` or set the parameters for a single loop.

The label distance can be set using the `label distance` key as part of the node style.  To move the label closer to the node, use a negative value. For this example `-3pt` seems to work nicely.  There doesn't seem to be a way to set this key for a single node.  So you can

Comment: @egreg how to close the `Foo` label to the `foo` node?

Comment: @juanuni I've added some information about the label distance.

Comment: Just a note, it seems like this information is not in section 50.4 of the documentation any longer. It might be in 52.4 instead.

Answer (score 16):

I tried some time ago to create a loop like a circle (exactly an arc of a circle, a bit rounder and nicer). I didn't find a easy way to do this, but here is the code I wrote to such loops.

First code: I used only TikZ but I used an empirical method to calculate some of the lengths.
The macro `\tikzAngleOfLine` gives me the angle of a line. If `\AngleEnd`is greater  than `\AngleSart` a problem appears. In the second code example I give a solution to this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc} 

\newcommand{\tikzAngleOfLine}{\tikz@AngleOfLine}
\def\tikz@AngleOfLine(#1)(#2)#3{%
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{%
\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,>=stealth']
\node [circle,draw,minimum size=2cm](A) {first node};
\node [circle,minimum size=3cm](B) at ([{shift=(60:1)}]A){};
\coordinate  (C) at (intersection 2 of A and B);
\coordinate  (D) at (intersection 1 of A and B);
 \tikzAngleOfLine(B)(D){\AngleStart}
 \tikzAngleOfLine(B)(C){\AngleEnd}
\draw[red,thick,->]%
   let \p1 = ($ (B) - (D) $), \n2 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
   in   
     (B) ++(60:\n2) node[fill=white]{$\alpha$}
     (D) arc (\AngleStart-360:\AngleEnd:\n2); % -360 only if  \AngleStart>\AngleEnd
 \end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

The result is [image: output of code]

Second code: Here I used some macros from the `tkz-euclide` package. The idea is to build an orthogonal circle to the first node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all} 
\usetikzlibrary{through}  
\newcommand{\tikzAngleOfLine}{\tikz@AngleOfLine}
\def\tikz@AngleOfLine(#1)(#2)#3{%
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{%
\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{\pgfmathresult}%
} 

\def\roundloop[#1]#2#3{%
 \coordinate (rla) at (#2.east); 
 \path   (#2)--++(#1) coordinate (rlb);
 \tkzTgtFromP(#2,rla)(rlb)            
 \node (rlb) at (rlb) [circle through={(tkzFirstPointResult)}] {};
 \coordinate  (rlc) at (intersection 2 of #2 and rlb);
 \coordinate  (rld) at (intersection 1 of #2 and rlb);         
 \tikzAngleOfLine(rlb)(rld){\AngleStart}
 \tikzAngleOfLine(rlb)(rlc){\AngleEnd} 
 \tikzAngleOfLine(#2)(rlb){\AngleLabel}
 \ifdim\AngleStart pt<\AngleEnd pt
 \draw[red,thick,->]%
   let \p1 = ($ (rlb) - (rld) $), \n2 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
   in   
     (rlb) ++(\AngleLabel:\n2) node[fill=white]{#3}
     (rld) arc (\AngleStart:\AngleEnd:\n2); 
 \else 
  \draw[red,thick,->]%
   let \p1 = ($ (rlb) - (rld) $), \n2 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
   in   
     (rlb) ++(\AngleLabel:\n2) node[fill=white]{#3}
     (rld) arc (\AngleStart-360:\AngleEnd:\n2); 
   \fi 
  }
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \node[circle,draw] (O){first node}; 
  \roundloop[180:2]{O}{$\alpha$}
   \roundloop[0:1]{O}{$\beta$}  
     \roundloop[60:3]{O}{$\delta$}
   \roundloop[-120:4]{O}{$\gamma$} 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: very nice solution. In my tikz picture i draw lines from node "A" to node "B". If i would like to use your concept and to place my number (in your example, $\alpha$, $\beta$, etc.) in the middle of the line. How should i change your code?

Comment: Wow! Great. A question: why is `\makeatletter` not required?

Answer (score 12):

You could adjust angles and looseness for example this way:

```
\path[->,every loop/.style={looseness=10}] (foo)
         edge  [in=120,out=60,loop] node {1} ();
```

[image: loop example]

Comment: how do i place the number above the loop?

Comment: @Eagle by `node[above] {1}`.

Comment: Note that apparently `in=120,out=60` has to be put _before_ `loop`. Otherwise compilation throws an error.