# Prevent oval loops when using Tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, automata

I'm just starting to learn LaTex, escpecially graphics, and this is my (simplified) code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every loop/.style={in=30,out=160,looseness=5}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto,bend angle=80] 
   \tikzstyle{place}=[circle,thick,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20,minimum
                            size=6mm]

   \node[state,initial] (s_0)   {$s_0$};

    \path[->]
    (s_0) edge [loop above] node {x} ();

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the loops are somewhat oval:

[image: Current version][image: Current version incl. lines]

I want the blue lines to be of equal length (second picture).

I found a [very impressive solution here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35469/38074), but I do not need text within the arc. So my question: is there any easier trick?

Comment: Use `out=150` (or `out=180-30`) if you’re using `in=30`? An adivce: Don’t put `out` and `in` values in the `every loop` style because all other loops (`loop right` and so on) use these directions, too. Rather change `loop above` directly.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Many thanks! I didn't think of such an obvious solution. I'll accept your answer if you post one.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Reading your advice, is there an option to set the `out/in` values only to every `loop above` combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want symmetrical loops (to the vertical axis) you need to use “symmetrical” `out` and `in` angles, in your case either

```
in=30, out=180-30
```

or

```
in=40, out=160
```

With the style `every loop` you will also change `loop right`, `loop left` and `loop below` which will then look like `loop above`.

Only change the `loop above` style, you will either need to overwrite it:

```
\tikzset{
  loop above/.style={% original: above, out=105, in=75, loop
    above, in=30, out=150, loop,
    every loop/.append style={looseness=5}}}
```

or append the needed options as an appendix to the `every loop` style:

```
\tikzset{loop above/.append style={every loop/.append style={out=150, in=30, looseness=5}}}
```

This is due to how the key `loop` and the keys `out`, `in` and `looseness` work (they reset the `to path` to the usual curve-to path that needs a target.