# TikZ Self Loops Style Question

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, loops, tikz-styles

I have a question on how to "style" the self loops in my diagram.

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{tufte-handout}

% Additional LaTeX Packages

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% LaTeX TikZ Graphics Package

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{
    >=stealth,
    auto,
    node distance=3.5cm,
    font=\scriptsize,
    possible world/.style={circle,draw,thick,align=center},
    real world/.style={double,circle,draw,thick,align=center},
    minimum size=40pt
}
```

and here is my current attempt at a diagram:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[real world] (1) {$\World_{1}$ \\ $H,L$};
\node[possible world] (2) [right of=1] {$\World_{2}$ \\ $\neg{H},L$};
\node[possible world] (3) [below of=1] {$\World_{3}$ \\ $\neg{H},L$};
\node[possible world] (4) [right of=3] {$\World_{4}$ \\ $\neg{H},L$};
\path[]
    (1) edge [loop above,thick] node {$A,B,C$} (1)
    (2) edge [loop above,thick] node {$A,B,C$} (2)
    (3) edge [loop below,thick] node {$A,B,C$} (3)
    (4) edge [loop below,thick] node {$A,B,C$} (4)
    (1) [<->,thick] edge node[above] {$B$} (2)
    (3) [<->,thick] edge node[below] {$A,B,C$} (4)
    (1) [->,thick] edge node[left] {$C$} (3)
    (1) [->,thick] edge node[right] {$C$} (4)
    (2) [->,thick] edge node[left] {$C$} (3)
    (2) [->,thick] edge node[right] {$C$} (4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Successor state, $\State_{2}$, obtained after $A$ peeks into the strongbox and learns that the coin is facing heads up without the knowledge of his fellow agents.}
\label{fig:multi-modal-strongbox:peek-2-successor}
\end{figure}
```

The picture that I am getting looks like this:

[image]

But I really want the arcs to look like the ones in this example:

[image]

I don't mind having the labels be above or below the arc and not in the middle, but the overall shape of the self loops is what I'm interested in replicating.

Also, as a side note - I've been unable to find a way to increase the horizontal separation between the nodes. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4778) instead of snippets. I have errors when I try to typeset it.

Comment: You can change the angles (`out` and `in`) as well as the `looseness` and/or the `distance` of the loops, see [Prevent oval loops when using Tikz package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137294)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `positioning` library to adjust the horizontal distance between `node`s. Also note that `right of =...` is replaced with `right = <dimen>cm of ...` here as the former is deprecated. You can put four extra nodes for `A, B, C` and adjust the `edge` with `in=...,out=...` parameters. As I don't know what `\World` etc are, I have replaced them with `World` etc. Further, I have adjusted `minimum size` at few places as you have globally defined it (which I wouldn't do generally).

Full code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{tufte-handout}

% Additional LaTeX Packages

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% LaTeX TikZ Graphics Package

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\tikzset{
    >=stealth,
    %auto,
    %node distance=3.5cm,
    font=\scriptsize,
    possible world/.style={circle,draw,thick,align=center},
    real world/.style={double,circle,draw,thick,align=center},
    minimum size=40pt
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[real world] (1) {$World_{1}$ \\ $H,L$};
\node[above = .1ex of 1,inner sep = 0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=25pt] (1a) {$A,B,C$};
\node[possible world] (2) [right = 5cm of 1] {$World_{2}$ \\ $\neg{H},L$};
\node[above = .1ex of 2,inner sep = 0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=25pt] (2a) {$A,B,C$};
\node[possible world] (3) [below = 2cm of 1] {$World_{3}$ \\ $\neg{H},L$};
\node[below = .1ex of 3,inner sep = 0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=25pt] (3a) {$A,B,C$};
\node[possible world] (4) [right = 5cm of 3] {$World_{4}$ \\ $\neg{H},L$};
\node[below = .1ex of 4,inner sep = 0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=25pt] (4a) {$A,B,C$};
\path[]
    (1) edge [in=180, out=130,thick] (1a)
    (1a) edge [->,in=50, out=0,thick] (1) 
    (2) edge [in=180, out=130,thick] (2a)
    (2a) edge [->,in=50, out=0,thick]  (2)
    (3) edge [in=180, out=230,thick] (3a)
    (3a) edge [->,in=310, out=0,thick]  (3)
    (4) edge [in=180, out=230,thick] (4a)
    (4a) edge [->,in=310, out=0,thick]  (4)
    (1) [<->,thick] edge node[above,minimum size=0pt] {$B$} (2)
    (3) [<->,thick] edge node[below,minimum size=0pt] {$A,B,C$} (4)
    (1) [->,thick] edge node[left,minimum size=0pt] {$C$} (3)
    (1) [->,thick] edge node[right] {$C$} (4)
    (2) [->,thick] edge node[left] {$C$} (3)
    (2) [->,thick] edge node[right,minimum size=0pt] {$C$} (4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Successor state, $State_{2}$, obtained after $A$ peeks into the strongbox and learns that the coin is facing heads up without the knowledge of his fellow agents.}
\label{fig:multi-modal-strongbox:peek-2-successor}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does that formula  **S** x **t** x **a** x **t** x **e** do? :P

Comment: Then why leaving it in? It's a typo-crime you know :)