# modify loops in tikz automaton

Tags: diagrams, tikz-arrows, automata

In this picture my code draws the red loops. I'd like to replace them with the hand drawn ones in black.

[image]

I've tried lots of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) with tikz options from [changing loop size and shape in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35423/changing-loop-size-and-shape-in-tikz) , [changing loop size and shape in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35423/changing-loop-size-and-shape-in-tikz) , [How to draw bigger circular states and multiple transitions in automata?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121846/how-to-draw-bigger-circular-states-and-multiple-transitions-in-automata)  and other sites, to no avail. Perhaps those interventions may not work properly with the automata library.

(I'd like larger arrowheads, too, thanks.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}
\tikzset{
->,  % makes the edges directed
>=stealth', % makes the arrow heads bold
node distance=2.5cm, %  minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
every state/.style={thick}, % sets the properties for each 'state' node
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state] (0) {$0$};
\node[state, right of=0] (1) {$1$};
\node[state, right of=1] (2) {$2$};
\node[state, right of=2] (3) {$3$};
\node[state, right of=3] (4) {$4$};
\node[state, right of=4] (5) {$5$};
% march down
\draw[thick](1) edge[bend right, above] (0);
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, above] (1);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, above] (2);
\draw[thick](4) edge[bend right, above] (3);
\draw[thick](5) edge[bend right, above] (4);
% skip dowo
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, above] (0);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, above] (1);
\draw[thick](4) edge[bend right, above] (2);
\draw[thick](5) edge[bend right, above] (3);
% march up
\draw[thick](1) edge[bend right, below] (2);
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, below] (3);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, below] (4);
\draw[thick](4) edge[bend right, below] (5);
% skip up
\draw[thick](1) edge[bend right, below] (3);
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, below] (4);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, below] (5);
% loops
\draw[thick] (1) edge[loop left, red] (1);
\draw[thick] (4) edge[loop right, red] (4);
\draw[thick] (5) edge[loop left, red] (5);
\draw[thick] (5) edge[loop right, red] (5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for `border=3.14mm` ;-)

Comment: @marmot I borrowd that margin from your answer to a previous question of mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}

\tikzset{
->,  % makes the edges directed
>=stealth', % makes the arrow heads bold
node distance=2.5cm, %  minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
every state/.style={thick}, % sets the properties for each 'state' node
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state] (0) {$0$};
\node[state, right of=0] (1) {$1$};
\node[state, right of=1] (2) {$2$};
\node[state, right of=2] (3) {$3$};
\node[state, right of=3] (4) {$4$};
\node[state, right of=4] (5) {$5$};
% march down
\draw[thick](1) edge[bend right, above] (0);
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, above] (1);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, above] (2);
\draw[thick](4) edge[bend right, above] (3);
\draw[thick](5) edge[bend right, above] (4);
% skip dowo
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, above] (0);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, above] (1);
\draw[thick](4) edge[bend right, above] (2);
\draw[thick](5) edge[bend right, above] (3);
% march up
\draw[thick](1) edge[bend right, below] (2);
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, below] (3);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, below] (4);
\draw[thick](4) edge[bend right, below] (5);
% skip up
\draw[thick](1) edge[bend right, below] (3);
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, below] (4);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, below] (5);
% loops
\draw[thick] (1) edge[loop left, red] (1);
\draw[thick] (4) edge[loop right, red] (4);
\draw[thick] (5) edge[loop left, red] (5);
\draw[thick] (5) edge[loop right, red] (5);
% back loops
\draw[thick] (1) edge[loop right, out=150, in=210, looseness=7] (1);
\draw[thick] (4) edge[loop right, out=330, in=30, looseness=7] (4);
\draw[thick] (5) edge[loop right, out=330, in=30, looseness=7] (5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

One can always write a style for such things... **EDIT**: Increased the arrows.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
->,  % makes the edges directed
>={Stealth[length=3.14mm]}, % makes the arrow heads bold
node distance=2.5cm, %  minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
every state/.style={thick}, % sets the properties for each 'state' node
my loop left/.style={out=165,in=195,loop},
my loop right/.style={out=-15,in=15,loop}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state] (0) {$0$};
\node[state, right of=0] (1) {$1$};
\node[state, right of=1] (2) {$2$};
\node[state, right of=2] (3) {$3$};
\node[state, right of=3] (4) {$4$};
\node[state, right of=4] (5) {$5$};
% march down
\draw[thick](1) edge[bend right, above] (0);
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, above] (1);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, above] (2);
\draw[thick](4) edge[bend right, above] (3);
\draw[thick](5) edge[bend right, above] (4);
% skip dowo
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, above] (0);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, above] (1);
\draw[thick](4) edge[bend right, above] (2);
\draw[thick](5) edge[bend right, above] (3);
% march up
\draw[thick](1) edge[bend right, below] (2);
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, below] (3);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, below] (4);
\draw[thick](4) edge[bend right, below] (5);
% skip up
\draw[thick](1) edge[bend right, below] (3);
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, below] (4);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, below] (5);
% loops
\draw[thick] (1) edge[my loop left, red] (1);
\draw[thick] (4) edge[my loop right, red] (4);
\draw[thick] (5) edge[my loop left, red] (5);
\draw[thick] (5) edge[my loop right, red] (5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you would like the loops to become bigger, you can adjust the `in` and `out` angles accordingly. Additionally, you may increase `looseness`, but I am not convinced of the outcome, but that's a matter of taste.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
->,  % makes the edges directed
>={Stealth[length=3.14mm]}, % makes the arrow heads bold
node distance=2.5cm, %  minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
every state/.style={thick}, % sets the properties for each 'state' node
my loop left/.style={out=160,in=200,loop},
my loop right/.style={out=-20,in=20,loop}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state] (0) {$0$};
\node[state, right of=0] (1) {$1$};
\node[state, right of=1] (2) {$2$};
\node[state, right of=2] (3) {$3$};
\node[state, right of=3] (4) {$4$};
\node[state, right of=4] (5) {$5$};
% march down
\draw[thick](1) edge[bend right, above] (0);
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, above] (1);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, above] (2);
\draw[thick](4) edge[bend right, above] (3);
\draw[thick](5) edge[bend right, above] (4);
% skip dowo
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, above] (0);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, above] (1);
\draw[thick](4) edge[bend right, above] (2);
\draw[thick](5) edge[bend right, above] (3);
% march up
\draw[thick](1) edge[bend right, below] (2);
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, below] (3);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, below] (4);
\draw[thick](4) edge[bend right, below] (5);
% skip up
\draw[thick](1) edge[bend right, below] (3);
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, below] (4);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, below] (5);
% loops
\draw[thick] (1) edge[my loop left, red] (1);
\draw[thick] (4) edge[my loop right, red] (4);
\draw[thick] (5) edge[my loop left, red] (5);
\draw[thick] (5) edge[my loop right, red] (5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for adding the code for bigger arrow heads. I was actually trying to remember it correctly, but couldn’t find it quickly enough. :)

Comment: @JasperHabicht I think the only thing to remember is that `arrows` got superseded by `arrows.meta`. And you can still add it to your nice answer that I upvoted, there is nothing wrong with that. This is a fun site, not competition.

Answer (score 2):

I've accepted @JasperHabicht 's answer, and upvoted @marmot 's. Posting my own here just to show how it all fits together.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
->,  % makes the edges directed
>={Stealth[length=3.14mm]}, % makes the arrow heads bold and bigger
%>=stealth', % makes the arrow heads bold
node distance=2.5cm, %  minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
every state/.style={thick}, % sets the properties for each 'state' node
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state] (0) {$0$};
\node[state, right of=0] (1) {$1$};
\node[state, right of=1] (2) {$2$};
\node[state, right of=2] (3) {$3$};
\node[state, right of=3] (4) {$4$};
\node[state, right of=4] (5) {$5$};
% march down
\draw[thick](1) edge[bend right, above] (0);
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, above] (1);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, above] (2);
\draw[thick](4) edge[bend right, above] (3);
\draw[thick](5) edge[bend right, above] (4);
% skip dowo
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, above] (0);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, above] (1);
\draw[thick](4) edge[bend right, above] (2);
\draw[thick](5) edge[bend right, above] (3);
% march up
\draw[thick](1) edge[bend right, below] (2);
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, below] (3);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, below] (4);
\draw[thick](4) edge[bend right, below] (5);
% skip up
\draw[thick](1) edge[bend right, below] (3);
\draw[thick](2) edge[bend right, below] (4);
\draw[thick](3) edge[bend right, below] (5);
% loops
\draw[thick] (1) edge[loop right, out=150, in=210, looseness=7] (1);
\draw[thick] (4) edge[loop right, out=330, in=30, looseness=7] (4);
\draw[thick] (5) edge[loop right, out=330, in=30, looseness=7] (5);
\draw[thick] (5) edge[loop right, out=330, in=30, looseness=9] (5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```