# Size of self pointing arrow and positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}% To get more advances positioning options
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}% To get more arrow heads
\usetikzlibrary{math,calc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{MyColor1}{rgb}{0.24, 0.59, 0.32}
\definecolor{MyColor2}{rgb}{0.85, 0.49, 0.19}
\definecolor{MyColor3}{rgb}{0.22, 0.42, 0.69}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2}{
        \draw[fill=MyColor1] (\x, 0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] (\x) {$V_{\x}$};    
    }
    \draw[fill=MyColor1] (3, 0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] (3) {$V_{n-1}$};
    \draw[fill=MyColor1] (4, 0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] (4) {$V_n$};

    \foreach \x in {-1,5}{
        \node at (\x,0) (\x) {$0$};
    }    
    \node at (2.5,0) {$\dots$};
    
    \draw[->, MyColor3] (0) to [out=75, in=105] (1) node at (0.5,0.95) {$e$};
    \draw[->, MyColor3] (1) to [out=75, in=105] (2) node at (1.5,0.95) {$e$};
    \draw[->, MyColor3] (3) to [out=75, in=105] (4) node at (3.5,0.95) {$e$};
    
    \node (tmp) at (-0.05,-0.35) {};
    \node (tmp2) at (0.05,-0.35) {};    
    
    \draw[->, MyColor2] ($(1)+ (tmp)$) to [out=-105, in=-75] ($(0)+(tmp2)$) node at (0.5,-0.6) {$f$};
    \draw[->, MyColor2] ($(2)+ (tmp)$) to [out=-105, in=-75] ($(1)+(tmp2)$) node at (1.5,-0.6) {$f$};
    \draw[->, MyColor2] ($(4)+ (tmp)$) to [out=-105, in=-75] ($(3)+(tmp2)$) node at (3.5,-0.6) {$f$};    
    
    \draw[->, MyColor2] ($(0)+ (-0.05,-0.35)$) to [out=-105, in=-75] ($(-1)+ (0.05,-0.15)$) node at (-0.5,-0.6) {$f$};
    \draw[->, MyColor3] (4) to [out=75, in=105] ($(5)+ (-0.05,0.53)$) node at (4.5,0.95) {$e$};    

    \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}{
        \path[->, MyColor1] ($(\x)+(0,0.3)$) edge [loop above, out=120, in=60, looseness=8] node {$h$} ($(\x)+(0.5,0.3)$);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces
[image]

I would like the green arrows to be pointing to itself. I therefore tried to modify the line

```
\path[->, MyColor1] ($(\x)+(0,0.3)$) edge [loop above, out=120, in=60, looseness=8] node {$h$} ($(\x)+(0.5,0.3)$);
```

to

```
\path[->, MyColor1] ($(\x)+(0,0.3)$) edge [loop above, out=120, in=60, looseness=8] node {$h$} ($(\x)+(0,0.3)$);
```

following the answer of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448388/modify-loops-in-tikz-automaton), but this results in only the arrow heads being drawn in place. I also tried the following

```
\path[->, MyColor1] ($(\x)+(-0.025,0.3)$) edge [loop above, out=120, in=60, looseness=8] node {$h$} ($(\x)+(0.025,0.3)$);
```

(baisically shifting the center to the label and then just making the gap between beginning and end smaller), but this resulted in a very small arrow... Can somebody maybe help a bit?

**PS:** I'm aware of the fact that I'm doing something wrong by constantly manipulating coordinates to specify beginning and end of arrows, etc. but I just don't really know how to do it otherwise.. If someone wants to suggest a solution for that as well, then it's obviously very appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}% To get more advances positioning options
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}% To get more arrow heads
\usetikzlibrary{math,calc}

\definecolor{MyColor1}{rgb}{0.24, 0.59, 0.32}
\definecolor{MyColor2}{rgb}{0.85, 0.49, 0.19}
\definecolor{MyColor3}{rgb}{0.22, 0.42, 0.69}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2}{
        \draw[fill=MyColor1] (\x, 0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] (\x) {$V_{\x}$};   
    }
    \draw[fill=MyColor1] (3, 0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] (3) {$V_{n-1}$};
    \draw[fill=MyColor1] (4, 0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] (4) {$V_n$};

    \foreach \x in {-1,5}{
        \node at (\x,0) (\x) {$0$};
    }   
    \node at (2.5,0) {$\dots$};

    \draw[->, MyColor3] (0) to [out=75, in=105] (1) node at (0.5,0.95) {$e$};
    \draw[->, MyColor3] (1) to [out=75, in=105] (2) node at (1.5,0.95) {$e$};
    \draw[->, MyColor3] (3) to [out=75, in=105] (4) node at (3.5,0.95) {$e$};

    \node (tmp) at (-0.05,-0.35) {};
    \node (tmp2) at (0.05,-0.35) {};    

    \draw[->, MyColor2] ($(1)+ (tmp)$) to [out=-105, in=-75] ($(0)+(tmp2)$) node at (0.5,-0.6) {$f$};
    \draw[->, MyColor2] ($(2)+ (tmp)$) to [out=-105, in=-75] ($(1)+(tmp2)$) node at (1.5,-0.6) {$f$};
    \draw[->, MyColor2] ($(4)+ (tmp)$) to [out=-105, in=-75] ($(3)+(tmp2)$) node at (3.5,-0.6) {$f$};   

    \draw[->, MyColor2] ($(0)+ (-0.05,-0.35)$) to [out=-105, in=-75] ($(-1)+ (0.05,-0.15)$) node at (-0.5,-0.6) {$f$};
    \draw[->, MyColor3] (4) to [out=75, in=105] ($(5)+ (-0.05,0.53)$) node at (4.5,0.95) {$e$}; 

    \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}{
        \path[->, MyColor1] (\x) edge [loop above, out=120, in=60, looseness=16]
        node {$h$} (\x);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem with your approach is that you turn nodes, i.e. extended object, into coordinates by using the `calc` syntax. It seems to me that you do not want that here.

You can simplify the code quite a bit.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}% To get more advances positioning options
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}% To get more arrow heads
\usetikzlibrary{math,calc}

\definecolor{MyColor1}{rgb}{0.24, 0.59, 0.32}
\definecolor{MyColor2}{rgb}{0.85, 0.49, 0.19}
\definecolor{MyColor3}{rgb}{0.22, 0.42, 0.69}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2}{
        \draw[fill=MyColor1] (\x, 0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] (\x) {$V_{\x}$};   
    }
    \draw[fill=MyColor1] (3, 0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] (3) {$V_{n-1}$};
    \draw[fill=MyColor1] (4, 0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] (4) {$V_n$};

    \foreach \x in {-1,5}{
        \node at (\x,0) (\x) {$0$};
    }   
    \node at (2.5,0) {$\dots$};

    \node (tmp) at (-0.05,-0.35) {};
    \node (tmp2) at (0.05,-0.35) {};    
    \foreach \X in {1,2,4}
    {\draw[->, MyColor3] (\the\numexpr\X-1.50) to [out=75, in=105]
     node[above]  {$e$}(\X.130)  ;
    \draw[->, MyColor2] ($(\X)+ (tmp)$) to [out=-105, in=-75]
        node[below]{$f$}($(\the\numexpr\X-1)+(tmp2)$) ;}

    \draw[->, MyColor2] ($(0)+ (-0.05,-0.35)$) to [out=-105, in=-75] ($(-1)+ (0.05,-0.15)$) node at (-0.5,-0.6) {$f$};
    \draw[->, MyColor3] (4.50) to [out=75, in=105] node[above] {$e$} ++ (0.5,0);  

    \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}{
        \path[->, MyColor1] ([xshift=-0.7ex,yshift=0.3ex]\x.north) edge [loop above, out=120, in=60, looseness=16]
        node {$h$} ([xshift=0.7ex,yshift=0.3ex]\x.north);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to not let the green and blue arrow intersect? Maybe by moving the green loop a bit higher and making the gap between the start and end a bit smaller? Otherwise this is exactly what I want.

Comment: @Sito Of course. I simplified the code and avoided the intersections in an update (the second example).

Comment: Looks very nice, thank you for the work!