# Draw loops in TikZ of different sizes and shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-path

I'm trying to draw a graph in TikZ with different-looking loops.

In the graph below, I would like to make one loop smaller and the other larger. I would also like to be able to control the shape or roundness of the loops.

The parameter "looseness" doesn't seem to do anything. Perhaps it is possible to use [control points](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255234/how-does-one-pick-control-points-to-control-b%C3%A9zier-curves-in-tikz)? I've been trying to draw a loop manually, without actually using "loop", but cannot get it to work when the starting and ending points are identical.

After reading [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35423/changing-loop-size-and-shape-in-tikz) I'm able to change size for both loops at once. The answer mentions that this is possible to do for individual loops with ".style", but not exactly how. (There's also a reference to a section in the TikZ documentation for more detail. I have looked [here](https://tikz.dev/library-edges) at 74.4, but didn't find any answers.)

Here's my code and the current output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every loop/.style={min distance=30mm}]

    \draw[thick] (0,0) to [out=-30,in=-150, loop] (0,0) -- (0,1);

    \draw[thick] (0,1) to [out=30, in=150, loop] (0,1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you edited my answer, feel free to accept whatever answer suits you, or ask for imporvements, if nedded.

Comment: Sure! I was just waiting to see whether the edit would be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a bit to help you with control points of Bezier curves:

[image: different size loops]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \newcommand{\dist}{3}
    \draw[thick]    (0,0) .. controls ++ (2*\dist,-\dist) and ++ (-2*\dist,-\dist) .. (0,0)
                    --
                    (0,1) .. controls ++ (\dist,\dist) and ++ (-\dist,\dist) .. (0,1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here I used a variable distance `\dist` to help you tr some values, but you can choose whatever value you need.

Know that I used `++` in order to define the control points relatively to the anchor points and not in absolute coordinates, where `++` would not be needed.

Answer (score 5):

To modify each loop individually, just change the style in the object options, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every loop/.style={min distance=30mm}]

    \draw[thick] (0,0) to [out=-20,in=-150, loop, style={min distance=12mm}] (0,0) -- (0,1);

    \draw[thick] (0,1) to [out=30, in=150, loop] (0,1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: First image]

Now, for the "roundness" of each loop, I wonder if two circles would better fit your goal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every loop/.style={min distance=30mm}]

    \draw[thick] (0,-0.5) circle (0.5);
    \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (0,1);
    \draw[thick] (0,1.5) circle (0.5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Second image]

Comment: Thanks! I considered circles, but thought that one could perhaps more flexibly modify the shape by changing "looseness" or with [control points](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255234/how-does-one-pick-control-points-to-control-b%C3%A9zier-curves-in-tikz). I will make a slight edit to my question (and also fix the asymmetry in the code for the lower loop).